# What is the difference between Essex and Folsom release of Openstack?

Tags: openstack

I am new to Openstack.

I have to find any API changes in Essex and Folsom release API. API changes means is there any parameter is added in new release? or is there any return value of the API is changed in new release?

I search on the net and what I understand from net is (correct me if I am wrong):

- Essex and Folsom are two release of Openstack.
- Essex and Folsom are not version changes. (means Essex is 2.0 and Folsom is 3.0)
- Nova(Compute), Horizone(Dashboard), Keystone(Identity service), Glance (Image Service) and Swift(Object Storage) are the different components of Openstack.
- Essex is released and Folsom is next release.
- What API describe in http://api.openstack.org/ are related to Essex release.

If you can help me to guide in this direction then, it will be help for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're two different versioned releases of OpenStack.

Essex was released in the spring of 2012 (release # 2012.1), Folsom is about to be released this month (will be release 2012.3).

The major changes will be covered in release notes, documented from the project here: http://wiki.openstack.org/ReleaseNotes/Folsom. Those release notes are still being filled in by the various project leads.

At a high level, the largest change is that the volume component/functionality has been broken out into it's own project (cinder), adding a new project to the OpenStack core. I'm not personally up to date on all the changes, but I believe the API has remained almost identical on most services. I know it has for Keystone (identity components), as we're still working on a "v3" api for keystone.